# How to find 'Add a Permission' button in 'Permissions' tab in SQS Queue after AWS redesigned the SQS console experience

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

AWS has redesigned the SQS console experience few days or a week before. I am not able to find the Permissions tab in the new version. Could anyone please share the screenshots how to navigate?

Answer (score 4):

To access the **Access Policy**:

- Click on the queue
- Go to the **Access policy** tab
- Click **Edit**

You will need to edit the policy in JSON. I think there was previously a simpler way to add permissions, but that method simply modified the policy. Now you need to edit the policy manually.

You can use the [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to help construct a policy.

Comment: Thank you so much, @John Rotenstein, for sharing the AWS Policy Generator link. You helped me in editing the policy very well!

Comment: The UI now has a link to the policy generator in it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like when first creating the queue in the new console, it has a wizard that lets you add other AWS accounts, IAM roles/users - but after the initial queue creation, if you go to edit the queue, that wizard isn't there.

[image: SQS permissions]